# XML error value="<?php ?>

Tags: php, xml, forms

I'm getting this error "XML Parsing Error: not well-formed" when validating my page for XML... I'm guessing it could be because of the < in the value attribute... would you think that is the error? And does anyone have a solution to it without removing the php code?

```
<form><input type="text" name="company" id="company" value="<?php echo $company = $_GET['company'];?>" /></form>
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I can see HTML and PHP in the posted snippet. Where is XML involved?

Comment: @axiac — HTML 5 has an XML serialisation which, aside from the errors reported in the question, this snippet conforms to.

Comment: **Danger**: This code is [vulnerable to XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS) User input needs escaping before being inserted into a document! (and you'd want it to be valid XML too!).

Answer (score 1):

> I'm guessing it could be because of the < in the value attribute... would you think that is the error?

It is. XMLLint reports:

> test.xml:1: parser error : Unescaped '<' not allowed in attributes values

---

> And does anyone have a solution to it without removing the php code?

Execute the PHP and validate the resulting XML with an XML validator.

Don't try to validate your PHP source code. PHP is not XML.

Answer (score -1):

Check your DOCTYPE or do you even have one in top of the code, it might solve this!

Comment: The additional rules that a DTD can provide will have no influence on a document being well formed or not. Using a DOCTYPE can't possibly help.